The task completes with the SKIPPED status if it was started outside the interval of the schedule_interval parameter
In my DAG setup, the schedule_interval parameter has a cron expression = run 1 time per hour from 5-12 and from 13-18. And one hour (from 12-13) outside this interval.
If you manually start a task (CLEAR Task) outside of this interval, it will not work and will immediately set the SKIPPED status. And if a task started at 11:30 does not have time to complete before 12 o'clock, then it ends with the SKIPPED status.
How is it treated?
What did you try and what were you expecting?

The problem is solved. It turned out that the "dagrun_timeout" parameter did not allow anything to run. I took it away and that's it.
